# MySql not found in Testlink Installation

Tags: mysql, xampp, testlink

Having trouble with the testlink installation. At the beginning of the installation it's giving me a warning saying:

> "Failed! MySQL Database cannot be used." and after I try to install it shows me this "Checking PHP DB extensions Warning!: Your PHP installation don't have the mysql extension mysql- without it is IMPOSSIBLE to use Testlink.Failed!". 
>   I installed Xampp before this, so I should have MySql, right? If it matters, I had to switch the Apache port numbers to 8080.

**Image 1:**

[image: Image1]

**Image 2:**

[image: Image2]]

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue, tried all given answers on different forums, but `nothing worked` for me unless I downgraded the version of Xampp to `32 bit installer` `version 5.6.36`.  [Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/5.6.36/) which simply solved the problem.

As per my understanding issue is testlink [mysql] is `not compatible` with the `latest version of PHP`.
I followed [this](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-install-and-setup-testlink-on.html) article to install but here also people faced similar issue as you can see comment section and there is no response from author on same. Rest of the article was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue configuring the extensions for SQL in file xampp's `php.ini`

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

DLLs should be in the path of the xampp installation, in my case `C:\xampp\php\ext\**`

Answer (score 1):

Click config then click PHP (php.ini) and add then following three lines

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

https://forum.testlink.org/viewtopic.php?t=2935
htis help me to fix it

Answer (score -1):

Some versions of PHP are not compatible with MySQL. Try reinstalling PHP using version 5.6

Comment: Please support your answer with more details.